# How to get visual studio to recognize a cshtml file as javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, dynamic-css

I am writing a css/js page that has some dynamic parts in it.
To do this i am using a cshtml file containing css/js - i am using mvc.net and returning the css from a controller action.

The trouble is visual studio recognizes this page as html and not as javascript/css so it does not give me javascript/css coloring and IntelliSense.

My questions:

1. is there a better/easier way of creating dynamic css/js in .net
2. How can i get visual studio to recognize a cshtml page as javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post...but...

What I did was just put the script tags around my javascript files in their own .cshtml file. 
I created a separate controller (JavascriptController.cs), and I created a filter on that controller that removes the script tags. I set the filter in the OnActionExecuting method. by just doing

```
this.Response.Filter = new ScriptFilter(Response.Filter, Response.ContentEncoding);
```

So you get the syntax, you get razor without having to use RazorJS, and you can request the js files like regular routes in an MVC application. You just have to keep the script tags on the partial view while editing.

So you can call

/Javascript/{Action}

and you'll get your javascript file with your razor in it, and the filter will remove the script tags so you can include it like a normal script.

```
<script src="http://{host}/Javascript/{action}"></script>
```

Comment: Good approach: This blog post goes into more detail, although it has some bugs that are addressed in the comments section. https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/07/07/generating-external-javascript-files-using-partial-razor-views?cachebreaker=635670317115705127#comment-20970

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to follow unobtrusive javascript and unobtrusive styling and put your javascript into a `.js` file, put your css into a `.css` file and reference them in the markup in your cshtml file with a `<script>` and `<link>` tag.

e.g.

```
<script src="Scripts/scriptName.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/styleSheetname.css" type="text/css" />
```

This is good practice as it keeps your content(markup)/styling/behaviour separate.

Comment: this will make you to enable razor for .js and .css which is not enabled by default

Comment: @vittore - How can i enable razor for js? that was exactly what i was looking for.
@stuperUser - i am looking for creating the js dynamically as i have small changes in different scenarios so i do not want a static js file.

Comment: @Daniel, it's possible to add data to the markup which is used by script as a flag/parameter to decide how to run rather than have dynamic code, if it needs to be testable.

Comment: @StuperUser - 
1. in what way is your method more testable? 
2. I would like to keep the css/js in 1 place what you are offering is to have bits of it on the page.
I will give your method a thought it will solve the problem of visual studio recognizing my code.

Comment: 1. You can test static JavaScript using e.g.  http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit, while testing dynamic script is possible, it's impractical and unreliable. 2. All the CSS should be together but separate from the JS and markup, as should the JS (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), the markup should, ideally, not contain any javascript or styles, only the tags to import the separate files.

Comment: 1. thanks for the tip i was not familiar with it.
2. I am leaving all the js/css in a seperate file i just want it to be created using razor/.net and not static. i think that being so i will not have a problem testing it if i wanted too (though i think in this project i will not need it).

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with putting `<script>` and `<style>` tags in a page and put your dynamic js/css there , in the end if it is dynamic there is no way for caching it so this approach will be fine.
you can write something like below:

```
<script>
 function myFunction_@MyFunc(params)(obj) {  return obj.field + @MyOtherFunc(params); }
<script>
```

and razor engine will evaluate @MyFunc(params) and @MyOtherFunc(params) before sending it to browser

Comment: This mixes behaviour with the markup and breaks unit-testability of the javascript.

Comment: @StuperUser: topic starter asked for dynamic js, which imho by default  do this

Comment: It is dynamic but with just a few scenarios (2 right now perhaps more in the future) so i was looking to have it cached.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript you could try the RazorJS nuget package. But we've run into some inconsistencies while using it.

Still trying to find a better way to do this using Controller/Views and still be able to use intellisense and get decent coloring.